# Computing entropy/disorder

Tags: algorithm

Given an ordered sequence of around a few thousand 32 bit integers, I would like to know how measures of their disorder or entropy are calculated.

What I would like is to be able to calculate a single value of the entropy for each of two such sequences and be able to compare their entropy values to determine which is more (dis)ordered.

I am asking here, as I think I may not be the first with this problem and would like to know of prior work.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE #1

I have just found [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/909) answer that looks great, but would give the same entropy if the integers were sorted. It only gives a measure of the entropy of the individual ints in the list and disregards their (dis)order.

Comment: I'm not sure you mean 'entropy'; I think you want **presortedness**.

Comment: Being in numeric order or not needs to add to entropy, but so does the range of values in the input, short term order, 'randomness', ...

Comment: P.S. Why the down votes on this question?

Comment: your update doesn't make any sense. it gives the same result if the "integers" (=characters) are sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'll have to code a shannon entropy in 2D. Arrange the list of 32 bit ints as a series of 8 bit bytes and do a Shannons on that, then to cover how ordered they may be, take the bytes eight at a time and form a new list of bytes composed of bits 0 of the eight followed by bits 1 of the eight ... bits 7 of the 8; then the next 8 original bytes ..., ...

I'll see how it goes/codes...

Answer (score 0):

Entropy calculation generally: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29

Furthermore, you have to sort your integers, then iterate over the sorted integer list to find out the frequency of your integers. Afterwards, you can use the formula.

Comment: Yep. I found something like that and have updated the question, but there is extra entropy in the disorder of the integers that is not being captured.

Answer (score 0):

Entropy is a function on probabilities, not data (arrays of ints, or files).  Entropy is a measure of disorder, but when the function is modified to take data as input it loses this meaning.

The only true way one can generate a measure of disorder for data is to use Kolmogorov Complexity.  Though this has problems too, in particular it's uncomputable and is not yet strictly well defined as one must arbitrarily pick a base language.  This well-definedness can be solved if the disorder one is measuring is relative to something that is going to process the data.  So when considering compression on a particular computer, the base language would be Assembly for that computer.

So you could define the disorder of an array of integers as follows:

The length of the shortest program written in Assembly that outputs the array.